# Android software runs differently based on different battery chargers?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, battery, charging

I have a Samsung Galaxy **Nexus** and a Samsung Galaxy **Mini2**.

In mid-August I lost my GNex battery charger; then I started charging the GNex with the Mini2 battery charger. 
Their specifications are:

```
GNex : Volt 5,0 Ampère 1.0
Mini : Volt 5,0 Ampère 0.7
```

Since the second battery charger has a lower Ampèrage, it *should* charge the phone exactly like the original one, but taking more time;

In mid-September, the GNex started doing strange things: the charge was degrading faster than before (I'm used to charge it every two days, while from mid-september I charged it every day), and THE PHONE BECAME SLOW. I mean **SLOW**.

Even if restarted and powered on from few minutes,  the Application button took about 4-5 seconds. Before it was instant and smooth, about 0.2 seconds.

In mid-October I found my original battery charger, and started using it again. After a couple of charges... the phone has returned to be superfast.

Talking with a friend (physicist), it said it must be a software (or hardware) thing. A wanted behavior set up in order to slow the phone down when not using the original battery charger. I said that it sounded a bit like conspiracy stuff, then he argued that it is more likely than the electrons remembering which battery charger transferred them and based on that deciding to slower the phone or not :)

Another friend (electrical engineering technician) said it is common practice (and brought examples from Laptop manufacturers's world);

Is this a known issue ? If yes, is this Google or Samsung's fault ? (Why on earth should they do something *that* stupid ? But this is rhetorical... )

Note: the "case study" is perfectly reproducible, the only requirement is to have two different battery chargers (with a different ampèrage) and a GNEx, but probably it is done on other phones too.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you running Android 4.3?

Comment: Yes, I'm running Android 4.3, Kernel 3.0.72. I own the GNex since Aug 2012, never installed strange things, never rooted, never ran out of space, never had a single problem. Best phone in history, until i switched battery charger :| BTW now I'm fine, I registered here just for curiosity, I'm not saying it MUST be a software or hardware issue nor a wanted / unwanted behavior, I'm just saying it act like that with one, and in the other way with the other... and the lower ampèrage ***alone*** could not scientifically explain that.

Comment: This is a confusing issue you had. I'd bet money that there are unknown circumstances with significant impact. Laptops are known to enter a low-power mode in certain circumstances, but Android phones certainly do not have multiple power modes depending on what they were charged with. The only instance of charger-pickiness that I've ever seen was with my old Motorola Atrix, which refused to charge from 0% with anything other than a Moto charger.

Comment: For what it's worth, I almost never charged my GNex from its original charger. It was always charged over USB or with various other chargers. Never had a problem with it.

Comment: I charge it with USB too sometimes... no problems with that. I would think like you about the unknown circumstances, but I can't think about any of them right now :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they don't behave differently if you don't use the original charger. I have a Samsung phone that has never even seen its original charger, along with some Nexus devices in similar conditions, and they don't suffer from slowdown or anything like this.

More likely, your phone is running low on internal storage, or you've recently installed an app that hogs the phone's CPU or RAM. There are lots of questions on the site about troubleshooting and debugging that kind of slowdown. Start by looking at the list of running apps in the phone's settings, browse those questions, and maybe ask a new one if you find something more specific.

Comment: Even if I'd strange stuff installed (and I don't), then why the phone returned immediately to run fast (from 4-5 seconds to 0.2 seconds), like before ? No un-installing, no space wiped, nothing. Your phone hasn't suffered this, maybe the other chargers have the same Ampèrage, or there is something else changing between our two situations. I'm not asking IF it does, I know it does. I'm asking WHY, and HOW. Thanks for answering btw

Comment: 4-5 seconds was in initial conditions, then cache came in the play and let's say that at the second pression of the Application button it tooks 2 seconds. But I've never ever seen the "round loading indicator" before on my phone.

Comment: @AndreaLigios, My experience as a former GNex owner is that Dan is 100% correct. This is most likely due to some condition of your device's local storage and could realistically be the result of any number of common solid-state storage caveats: possible culprits include degrading NAND, running low on internal storage (and thus unable to effectively cache files), or if you're on Android 4.2 or lower, lack of TRIM support. These kinds of things are actually nearly-universal to all smartphones. Try picking up an iPhone 4 or any Android phone on its original OS and it won't perform how it used to.

Comment: @dotVezz I'm aware that the degradation alone could be due to any kind of reason listed above. I'm not explaining myself that it returned immediately to its state when starting charging it with its charger. That's almost unexplainable, unless we think at a VERY weird coincidence, like some software upgraded in the same time, with a bug, and upgraded again with the bug resolved in the same time I started using its battery charger. And the bug should have affected the system, not only the application... I'm really, really curious about this.

Comment: I'll accept the answer because now, sometimes, it's happening again (it *seems* related to multiple chrome tabs opened, i'll investigate deeply); then it must have been some really, really weird coincidence. BTW the battery chargers should not be involved.